# Get mobile service client as a global variable and store the data in Azure from another class in Android

Tags: android, azure

I have authenticated using azure and for that I have used mobile service client in one activity and the next activity has to add some data so I need mobile service client to store data in the Azure DB. How can I do that? Please provide me some solutions.

Here is the code below for the authentication using mobile service client in login activity below:

```
public static MobileServiceClient mClient;

public MobileServiceTable<User> mUser;

public static MobileServiceTable<Location> mLocation;



    try {

        // Create the client instance, using the provided mobile app URL.

        mClient = new MobileServiceClient(url, this);

        mClient.setAndroidHttpClientFactory(new OkHttpClientFactory() {

            @Override
            public OkHttpClient createOkHttpClient() {

                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                client.setReadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                client.setWriteTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                return client;
            }
        });
        //connecting the azure user table dbo.users

        mUser = mClient.getTable("User", User.class);

        mLocation = mClient.getTable("Location", Location.class);
```

adding user in the azure db is like

public User addItemInTable(User data) throws ExecutionException,

InterruptedException {

```
                User entity;

                entity = mUser.insert(data).get();

                gotomaps();

                return entity;

}
```

Now I need to store the location in Azure using the mclient as above for user.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description.

**To store data in Azure, We can do as below:**

```
public Location addLocation(MobileServiceTable<Location> table, Location location){
      return table.insert(location).get();
}
```

Usage:

```
MobileServiceTable<Location> table = mClient.getTable("Location", Location.class);
Location location=new Location();
//....
addLocation(table, location);
```

**To set the service client as a global variable, we can use [android.app.Application] to achieve this.**

[android.app.Application] has the only one instance in the whole app life cycle. Here is a simple demo for you:

Create a class extends [android.app.Application]

```
package cn.azurepro.test.global;

import android.app.Application;

import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private MobileServiceClient mobileServiceClient=null;


    public void setMobileServiceClient(MobileServiceClient mobileServiceClient){
        this.mobileServiceClient=mobileServiceClient;
    }

    public MobileServiceClient getMobileServiceClient(){
        return mobileServiceClient;
    }

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}

}
```

Set the full name of this class as the name attribute of Application as below:

[image]

Then we can use it in different activities as below:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MyApplication myApplication= (MyApplication) this.getApplication();
        mClient = myApplication.getMobileServiceClient();
```

Comment: so i also wanted to ask when i add authentication from azure and azure asks auhentication everytime i invoke an api ..can you explain if i have to update the table data from another class .because using the mclient like this didnot help me in sending data to azure DB .

Comment: @season Do you mean that you want to get the location in one activity and in another activity you need to use this location?

Comment: @season If the issue was resolved, you can mark the helpful post as answer to help other community members find the helpful information quickly.